# regex replace all backward slashes before '\?'

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string such as

```
'frontend\less\defaults\layout.css?file=\foo'
```

I want a regex that replaces it with

```
'frontend/less/defaults/layout.css?file=\foo'
```

I tried `/\\/g`, but it keeps matching stuff after a `\?`, which I want to avoid somehow

Comment: And I assume those backslashes are escaped?

Answer (score 2):

Following will work, use a lookahead in your regexp:

```
var myString="path\\to\\file.php?query=\\something"
var r=(/\?/g.test(myString))?/(\\)(?=.+[\?])/ig:/\\/ig;
    .replace(r,"/")
```

Comment: awesomeness, I definitely need to learn how to use lookaheads

Comment: This is not going to work when the string does not contain the query part. e.g. `frontend\less\defaults\layout.css`

Comment: I had to look it up as well since regexp always gives me a head ache, this is a good resource: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev2.shtml

Comment: @nhahtdh Good point, I will update my answer to check for the ? in the string and make sure there is only one ? in there. I guess if there are more than it would not be a valid url.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `String.replace`, with a replacement function:

```
str.replace(/^([^?]*)/, function (_, $1) {
    return $1.replace(/\\/g, '/');
});
```

This will work regardless of whether the query string exists or not.

**Explanation**

```
/^([^?]*)/
```

`([^?]*)` will match and capture everything before `?` (if any).

I assume the URL is valid, so there is no validation done here.

(Thanks to @Pumbaa80 for the suggestion. There is no need to match the query string part if it is going to stay the same after the replacement)

Comment: This can be simplified to `str.replace(/^[^?]+/g, function(x){return x.replace(/\\/g,'/');})`

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know the number of `\`'s in advance, I doubt you can do this with a comprehensible regex. I would:

- split the string in two parts: the part before the `?`, and after it
- use your regex on the first part
- put the two strings back together.

Comment: You don't really need to split it into 2 parts. Replace function in JS can take in a function.

Comment: regexp can look ahead and only match \ if followed by ? so any \ after ? won't be matched unless there are multiple ? characters in there but that would make it an invalid query

Comment: @Pumbaa80: HMR has a fully regex-based solution, but I wouldn't call it comprehensible.